# UWP: How to prevent from loading data on Splash Screen

Tags: c#, uwp

In my UWP app I load some data after program is started. I want to show a progress ring during this process. However, program only moves from splasch screen when data is already loaded. How can I force program to load thee page with the progress ring and then load data?
Code:

```
private async void AutoLogin()
    {
        var parameter = new Login();

        parameter.Host = _host;
        parameter.Port = _port;
        parameter.DBname = _DBname;
        parameter.User = _user;
        parameter.Password = _password;

        string connString =
        String.Format(
            "Server={0}; User Id={1}; Database={2}; Port={3}; Password={4}; SSL Mode=Prefer; Trust Server Certificate=true",
            parameter.Host,
            parameter.User,
            parameter.DBname,
            parameter.Port,
            parameter.Password);
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            if(conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {

                conn.Close();
                await LoadPage(parameter);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AutoLoginRing.IsActive = false;
            AutoLoginRing.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            LoginStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }


    }

    async Task LoadPage(Login parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), parameter);
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {

            var dialog = new ContentDialog()
            {
                Title = "Critical Error!",
                Content = "Could not load Areas page. Restart the app or contact with the Support",
                CloseButtonText = "Ok"
            };
            ContentDialogResult result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using to load the data

Comment: @Fabulous It follows the scheme below:
string connString = String.Format( "Server={0}; User Id={1}; Database={2}; Port={3}; Password={4}; SSL Mode=Prefer; Trust Server Certificate=true", parameter.Host, parameter.User, parameter.DBname, parameter.Port, parameter.Password); NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString); try { conn.Open(); if(conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); } } catch (Exception ex) {}

Comment: Edit your question and include that code in there

Comment: However, It is not a problem, problem is in calling it from a right place in code. Both OnNavigated method and xaml page Loaded event do not work.

Comment: Where are you calling it from currently?

Comment: I have added a Loaded event in Xaml and I call it from Loaded dependant method.

Answer (score 2):

Both page's constructor and it's `OnNavigatedTo` method must finish for the splash screen to disappear as they both run on the UI thread. This means you should perform any loading either afterwards or asynchronously.

Consider the following example:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);        
    ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

As you might expect, this will cause the splash screen to stay on for five seconds. Whereas here:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

The page shows up as soon as possible. This is because `await` essentially "ends" the `OnNavigatedTo` event handler execution until the delay is over, freeing the UI thread which is then free to complete the navigation, and the waiting happens on another thread. Of course just waiting for the sake of waiting is useless, but I included the example for demonstration of how you can achieve faster navigation - minimize the amount of work in page constructor and `OnNavigatedTo` before the first `await`.

You could even move your logic to another thread using `await Task.Run( ... )`, but you would have to make sure you use `Dispatcher` when you need to run UI-related operations like accessing control or modifying data-bound properties.

Comment: Using this method I have an error that the MainPage, to which I do navigate after loading data does not exist in current context. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please update your question, I don't think I understand correctly. On which line does the exception occur? What exactly happens?

Comment: I have just updated the code to the real one, as I could not do it earlier.

Comment: How can I use your method to: 1. Show progress ring; 2. Try to connect to database; 3. Load next page or show controls (depend on the result of the second point.